# Can someone explain this Javascript closure example

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function makeAdder(x) {
    return function(y) {
        console.log("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
        return x + y;
  };

}

var add5 = makeAdder(5);
var add10 = makeAdder(10);

console.log(add5(2));
console.log(add10(2));
```

Ok, I am a bit confused with this example on developer.mozilla under closures.

If someone can explain with as much detail as possible in order for me to get my head around closures.

Ignore the console.log, I just added that to see what values are displayed and from that I can see that x is 5 and y is 2 when you execute add5 for example.

I consoled add5() to see what I get and I got NaN - and I am guessing that is because I have not specified an argument because it wants one and can't add a number to undefined.

So the confusion is that argument y in madeAdder's inner function.

Hope someone can provide a much better explanation than mozilla...i think the clue is environments but I'm new to this so need help from experts.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly don't you understand, what "*confusion*" do you have? What is the question? Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572?

Comment: Your hunch about `NaN` is correct.

Comment: Just reading what you provided above. My confusion is really the 'y'.

Comment: That's the parameter of the returned function, i.e. the argument of `add5` or `add10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeAdder(x) {
    return function(y) {
        console.log("X:" + x + " Y:" + y);
        return x + y;
    };
}
```

`makeAdder` required one parameter called `x` and returns a new function requiring the parameter `y`. When executing this inner function, the `x` of the outer scope will be added to the parameter `y` and the sum is returned.

`var add5 = makeAdder(5);` will create a new instance of the inner function and store it to `add5`. `x` for this inner function is set to `5`. when executing `add5` with `add5(2)` this will return `7`, because the `x` value ( outer scope `5` ) will be added to the parameter `2`.

The procedure for `add10` is equaly.

**Edit** when not passing a parameter ( either inner or outer function or both ) the parameter ( `y` or `x` or both ) will be `undefined`. `undefined+number` or `undefined+undefined` returns `NaN` because one or more of the summand is not a number.

**Edit 2**: Procedure Walkthrough:

`var add5 = makeAdder(5);` will set `add5` to:

```
function(y) {
   console.log("X:" + 5 + " Y:" + y);
   return 5 + y;
}
```

Because `makeAdder(5)` returns its inner function and sets x to 5. So when now executed with `var sum = add5(2);` this generated function will calculate and return `5 + y` (`5 + 2`).

*Note: it's not really setting x to `5` ( instead its still a reference to the outer x ) but i think this is easier to understand and does not change anything in this particular example*

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but I'm still confused with the 'y' variable.

Comment: I'll explain why...it all makes sense but how does it decide that add5(2) should be 'y' and not 'x'. Sorry if i sound stupid.

Comment: did this explain your questions, if so, please mark as solved